# How to dynamically change my includes to js files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a hidden div which contains my new links:

```
<div id="links" style="display:none">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    ...
</div>
```

The links I want to change are in my head:

```
<head id="myHead">
    <!-- My olds links I want to replace -->
</head>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
updateLinks();
function updateLinks() {
    var str = document.getElementById("links").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("myHead").innerHTML = str;
}
```

But my head don't receive the new links.

I want to update my links because I download html files and when I try to open them I have *ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND*

Can you help me please?

Comment: Whats wrong with loading library files directly in head like `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`?

Comment: It's just an example of include I don't have problem with jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want is a asyncrounous module loader (AMD) like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).
You can load all you files on demand. Using it it's simple to implement a lazy script loader. :)

Answer (score 3):

Would simply loading the new js scripts suffice for your purposes?

You could use the jQuery method *getScript* to call it for each attribute src of your scripts in your div, like:

```
$("#links script").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $.getScript( src, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        console.log( data ); // Data returned
        console.log( textStatus ); // Success
        console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
        console.log( "Load was performed." );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
$(function() {
    updateLinks();
});

function updateLinks() {
    var po = document.querySelector('#links script');
    var s = document.querySelector('head'); 
    s.appendChild(po, s)
}
```

The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BenoitNgo/6vca82wh/11/
The question has been answered already on this forum.